# exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver' SQLSRV Laravel Artisan CLI

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, command-line-interface

I am running php 5.5 on a Windows Server 2008. I am using the Laravel 4.0 framework for the application. I am connecting to a SQL SRV database via PDO, when executed via http there is no issue, connections are made data is called and updated without issue.

However when calling a command from Artisan (Laravel's CLI tool) I get the following error in the log:

```
log.ERROR: exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver' in C:\inetpub\MBSWeb\postsrch\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:47
Stack trace:
#0 C:\inetpub\MBSWeb\postsrch\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php(47): PDO->__construct('sqlsrv:Server=H...', 'xxxxxx', 'xxxxxx', Array)
#1 C:\inetpub\MBSWeb\postsrch\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\SqlServerConnector.php(29): Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector->createConnection('sqlsrv:Server=H...', Array, Array)
#2 C:\inetpub\MBSWeb\postsrch\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\ConnectionFactory.php(41): Illuminate\Database\Connectors\SqlServerConnector->connect(Array)
#3 C:\inetpub\MBSWeb\postsrch\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager.php(128): Illuminate\Database\Connectors\ConnectionFactory->make(Array, 'sqlsrv')
#4 C:\inetpub\MBSWeb\postsrch\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager.php(64): Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager->makeConnection('sqlsrv')
#5 C:\inetpub\MBSWeb\postsrch\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager.php(242): Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager->connection()
#6 C:\inetpub\MBSWeb\postsrch\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php(206): Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager->__call('table', Array)
#7 C:\inetpub\MBSWeb\postsrch\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php(206): Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager->table('bb_job_details')
#8 C:\inetpub\MBSWeb\postsrch\app\models\Job.php(214): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic('table', Array)
#9 C:\inetpub\MBSWeb\postsrch\app\models\Job.php(214): Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::table('bb_job_details')
#10 C:\inetpub\MBSWeb\postsrch\app\models\Cron.php(18): Job::getJobDetailsByStatus()
#11 C:\inetpub\MBSWeb\postsrch\app\controllers\ApplicantController.php(14): Cron::ChangePostingJobStatus()
#12 C:\inetpub\MBSWeb\postsrch\app\commands\GetApplicantsCommand.php(45): ApplicantController->index()
#13 C:\inetpub\MBSWeb\postsrch\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Command.php(108): GetApplicantsCommand->fire()
#14 C:\inetpub\MBSWeb\postsrch\vendor\symfony\console\Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command.php(244): Illuminate\Console\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#15 C:\inetpub\MBSWeb\postsrch\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Command.php(96): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#16 C:\inetpub\MBSWeb\postsrch\vendor\symfony\console\Symfony\Component\Console\Application.php(897): Illuminate\Console\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#17 C:\inetpub\MBSWeb\postsrch\vendor\symfony\console\Symfony\Component\Console\Application.php(191): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(GetApplicantsCommand), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#18 C:\inetpub\MBSWeb\postsrch\vendor\symfony\console\Symfony\Component\Console\Application.php(121): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#19 C:\inetpub\MBSWeb\postsrch\artisan(59): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
#20 {main} [] []
[2014-03-23 22:53:13] log.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Call to undefined function Symfony\Component\Console\mb_detect_encoding()' in C:\inetpub\MBSWeb\postsrch\vendor\symfony\console\Symfony\Component\Console\Application.php:721
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Exception\Handler->handleShutdown()
#1 {main} [] []
```

The PDO SQLSRV lib is installed, see the below screenshot of the **phpinfo()**, and as I've already said I can connection without issue when using the application via http;

[image: My php info.]

Why is the PDO connection working fine via http but not in CLI? **Please note** I'm using the exact same set of code, one is called from a Laravel controller, the other from a Laravel command.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

php cli and php cgi use different php.ini files. Try `php -i | grep pdo` to see if pdo is installed for your cli, see `php -i | grep "Loaded Configuration File"`

Comment: Thank you, you pointed me in the right direction. I had to use the Windows command php -i | find /i "Configuration File" . It turned out the CLI was using another version of php. I changed the PATH variable and now it all works good.

Comment: Could also just use `php --ini` (which works cross-platform) to get the CLI `.ini` file location.

Comment: Is there a way to install mssql by terminal on a mac running MAMP?

Comment: @MichelAyres you should create a top level question, instead of asking in the comments. That's what makes SO work the best.

Answer (score 2):

The answer above is correct, but just to clarify:

1. Open your console and execute:

   php -i | grep "Loaded Configuration File"
2. That will give you the folder directory where you php-cli.ini is (Laravel Commands use a different php.ini than the one used by HTTP requests)
3. Go to that file, and make sure it has this:

   extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
4. Restart your server and try again. That worked for me, hope it helps.

Comment: Just to clarify a bit more, restarting the server also means restarting php-fpm, if that's what you're using.